# how to get latest record based on range of date in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

Hi Everyone i am trying to get latest record between two range of date
Suppose i have select date between '2022-08-01' and '2022-08-03', please help me out.

current table

| id | cust_name | amount | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 100 | 2022-08-01 |
| 2 | A | 150 | 2022-08-02 |
| 3 | B | 100 | 2022-08-01 |
| 4 | B | 300 | 2022-08-02 |
| 5 | B | 50 | 2022-08-03 |
| 6 | B | 100 | 2022-08-04 |
| 7 | C | 200 | 2022-08-02 |

Expected output-:

| id | cust_name | amount | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | A | 150 | 2022-08-02 |
| 5 | B | 50 | 2022-08-03 |
| 7 | C | 200 | 2022-08-02 |

Comment: @RiggsFolly no my expected result is right i want result latest date record between range of gate and group by cust_name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I filtered out the dates and chose the latest date per *cust_name* using `row_num`.

```
select   id
        ,cust_name  
        ,amount 
        ,date
from    (
         select   *
                 ,row_number() over(partition by cust_name order by date desc) as rn
         from     t
         where    date between date '2022-08-01' and date '2022-08-03'
         ) t        
where   rn = 1
```

| id | cust_name | amount | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | A | 150 | 2022-08-02 00:00:00 |
| 5 | B | 50 | 2022-08-03 00:00:00 |
| 7 | C | 200 | 2022-08-02 00:00:00 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=352a701debff217115cd0b582ec81efd&hide=1)